# Mule: intercepting any kind of logging and adding messages to a list

Tags: java, logging, mule

Throughout my flows I have the "logger" component that writes important messages to the log. Mule itself is also outputting "INFO" and "ERROR" logging information that is important for another part of my application. Now, I would like to send all the log messages away to another application when the flow execution is finished. I am thinking the right way to do this is to create an interceptor, add the messages to a list set as a flow variable, and send it away at the end of the flow execution. But I would also like the logger.debug(), logger.info(), that I have in my custom component Java code to also be added to the list and sent away.

Would using an interceptor be the right way to do this?

Comment: I found an interesting article on logging interceptors that looks promising: http://www.javaroots.com/2013/08/logging-with-interceptor-mule-rest.html

However I'm wondering if there is a way not to tie the logging interceptor to only one component but to the entire flow, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a different appender in your log4j configuration for the application. This allows you to use JMS as appender.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Another option would be to use Mule server notifications to take into account only messages flowing through message processors:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications

Comment: I'm looking into this solution. However, I need to have access to a value from my payload when using the appender. Is this possible?

Comment: I need to keep the log messages in memory until the last component of my flow, and I want to be able to dissociate the log of one flow execution from another (different payload value.)
In my payload I have a value "identifier" which is a custom unique identifier for the current payload being sent. I would like to have a hashmap in memory with the identifier as the key string and a list of strings for the log messages. The point where I'm stuck currently is getting a hold of the variable with the appender. I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: Take a look at the Server Notifications alternative then. You can use beans as listeners and add whatever logic you need there.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a simpler way rather, at the end of flow drop a message to a vm to read the log file, another flow would be listening to this vm endpoint and start reading the log. Keeping it in a separate flow will give us more control on the log file to read different type of messages.

Comment: So you're suggesting reading the log files? I want each message as a list though, so does this mean I'd have to read a text file and somehow "parse" it again to get each message separately?

Comment: How would I know a message in the log file is for a given flow execution (For a given payload) as opposed to another payload that was processed around the same time?